# Entity Framework 4 Image Type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using Entity Framework 4 code-first with SQL Server CE 4.

What is the type I should define in the class? SQL Server CE only support `Image`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `byte[]` in your class.

The "image" db type is a bit misleading, as it just represents arbitrary binary data (full SQL Server has deprecated it in favor of the `varbinary(max)` type)

---

In your context class, you can try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourClass>().Property(x => x.YourProperty)
            .HasColumnType("image").IsMaxLength();
```

(I don't have any SQLCE projects to try it; maybe it will work, maybe not, maybe only one of the configuration methods is enough)

Comment: sql-server-ce is little different from sql-server.

Comment: @KelvinFixx it has differences, but the `image` type works the same way in both.

Comment: The byte[] create varbinary(4000) not varbinary(max).